# How does play.golang.org auto-manage imports?

Tags: go

Is there an open source JavaScript library that golang.org uses for Go Playgrounds? How does the Imports checkbox know which imports to add?

http://play.golang.org/p/A0nH96VB4S

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It uses the [`goimports`](https://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/go.tools/cmd/goimports) tool.

`goimports` works as a direct replacement for `gofmt`, with all the same options.

Comment: Is this common for Gophers to use? I know it exists but I've never really had any issues between environments and `go get`ting the dependencies myself.

Comment: This has nothing to do with getting dependencies. It does what gofmt does, plus automatcly rewrites the import section in your sources files to include only what's needed in the source.

Comment: Ohhh I thought it `go get`ted dependencies for you too. Is that not the case? Sounds like its something I should have in my toolbox either way.